# NSPopover dismissal does not remove it from parent's presentedViewControllers (Xcode 11)

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nspopover

Using Xcode 11 & macOS 10.15, I have a `ParentViewController` that presents a `PopoverViewController` in `.transient` mode (= clicking outside the popover dismisses it).

When the user clicks outside the Popover, it is properly dismissed and the `PopoverViewController` is properly **removed** from `ParentViewController.presentedViewControllers`. --> OK

BUT, I have a button inside the popover that calls `self.dismiss(self)`. The Popover is dissmised but **not removed from** `ParentViewController.presentedViewControllers`. --> PROBLEM

I do not think I've had this problem before.

Am I missing something here, or is this a bug in AppKit?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, I was doing it wrong.

As the documentation says, you have to call the dismiss from the presenting view controller.

Thus using `self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(self)` in the presented view controller solved the issue.